# WCF 4 Routing Services Protocol bridging issue (nettcp exposed services)

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, nettcpbinding, wcf-routing

We are confronted with a WCF Routing Services 4.0 issue. We are doing protocol bridging from http to net.tcp, our net.tcp WCF services are hosted in IIS 7.5 within AppFabric 1.1. This issue occurs both on Windows 7 dev boxes and on Windows 2008 R2 server. The problem is that after an IIS ApplicationPool recycling or ApplicationPool stop an System.ObjectDisposedException on the Routing Services occurs and on the next call to the Routing Services it will throw System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException:
This channel can no longer be used to send messages as the output session was auto-closed due to a server-initiated shutdown. Either disable auto-close by setting the DispatchRuntime.AutomaticInputSessionShutdown to false, or consider modifying the shutdown protocol with the remote server.

At this point all further calls  through Routing Services cannot be done. Strange is that this issue doesn’t come up if WCF Services, exposed via net.tcp, are self-hosted. So if you close a console host, where WCF services are hosted and then open it again, routing services are working again. This recovery is missing in case of IIS hosted WCF services, exposed via net.tcp binding.

In order to reproduce this issue we took Ex8-ProtocolBridging solution from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_whatsnewinwcf4_topic17.aspx and added an IIS hosted version of CalculatorService called CalculatorServiceIis.

I downloaded solutions files and the Word file “DescribedIssue.docx” to https://rapidshare.com/files/3527502127/ProtocolBridgingIssue.zip. you can find there the full description how to reproduce that issue.